# How to retrieve words from Wiki-words-250-with-normalization

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, embedding

I uploaded embedding:
embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-250-with-normalization/2")

the shape of the embedding matrix is 1009375x250 and I can get easily an embedding vector per word using x=embed(["hello"]) for example.

I would like to get all the words that exist in the embedding matrix. ie "a", .."apple", ..."Zulu", ... etc - the whole dictionary... 
how can I get them?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the dictionary in tokens.txt in the assets subdirectory within the api directory.